# XML LINQ Followup

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Ok, I have the results I need from my last question but I could use some help with another little issue.

I get a result set looking something like this:

```
[foo], [1, 1, 1, 1]
[bar], [2]
[baz], [3, 3, 3, 3]
[buz], [4]
```

The data type is a `KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>` and I need to get the result set (The Value part of the `KeyValuePair`) to look like this:

```
[foo], [1, 1, 1, 1]
[bar], [2, 2, 2, 2]
[baz], [3, 3, 3, 3]
[buz], [4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Is there a way with LINQ, Lambda Expressions or any other means to easily accomplish this? And yes, the values are repeated values. There is no uniqueness associated here, just the number of values necessary. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you're going to reference your last question, it would be helpful if you at least provided a link to it. Each question should be able to stand on its own.

Comment: Yeah, you should structure this question like it's a brand new question.  Don't make people sift through your old question to try and figure out what you're talking about.

Comment: To get better answer, you need to show your code

Comment: @SivaCharan: It's in the old question. :)

Comment: Just one question - what `xml` means in this particular case?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: It's in the old question. :)

Comment: Sorry about that ... I'll just delete this ...

Comment: @RobertHarvey .. I apologize for the confusion on this question but I got the answer I needed. I will make sure to frame questions better in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ and the main clue here is to use conditional operator to `Concat` remaining elements if list is too small:

```
var max = data.Max(p => p.Value.Count);
var result = 
data.Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(
            p.Key,
            p.Value.Count == max 
               ? p.Value 
               : p.Value.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(p.Value.First(), 
                                                  max - p.Value.Count))
                        .ToList())
           );
```

Comment: This works awesome but I have another condition to throw out there. Let's say that there are two sequences of repeated sets that are not sequential. Taking the above scenario, add 6 more bits to that array starting at 5 and ending at 10. I want to have 7 through 8 to repeat 4 times as well while keeping the integrity of the sequence numbers. Will the above LINQ statement continue to work with that scenario?